# JavaFX: How to slide image

Tags: java, javafx, slide, pane

How to make image to slide on the pane. I am looking at a functionality similar to Google Maps. When the user swipes (or drags or whatever the name of this event is), I need the image to change its position with regard to the pane it is located in.

Can anyone point at the direction where to look at. Is there anything build in in javafx for this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you 1. be more specific about the functionality you want, and 2. show what you have tried?

Comment: @James_D 1. I have a large Imageview on a pane which has some children elements on it. What I am trying to do is to a add some sort of sliding functionality. For example like Google Maps has when there are markers on it. User can drag the mouse and kinda swipe it. 2. With regard to this functionality, I didn't try anything. I have no idea how to add this functionality

Comment: @fabian drag and drop is not what I am looking for

Comment: @Alex But you said in your previous comment "User can drag the mouse". So you want dragging functionality or not? [Edit] you question to make it clearer what you mean (it is still not clear, at least not to me).

Comment: @James_D I don't know how this works. That's why I am posting the question. I gave and  example of what final functionality I am looking for. If this can be achieved by dragging, its fine. Repeating myself, an example of functionality I am looking for is how the mouse interaction works when users swipe (I assume this is the correct name of the event) on Google Maps and the displayed picture moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ScrollPane`'s scroll position can be adjusted by holding down the mouse button and moving the mouse, if the [`pannable` Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#pannableProperty) is set to `true`:

```
// Beware 5400x2700 px image 2MB
Image image = new Image("http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73751/world.topo.bathy.200407.3x5400x2700.jpg", true);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
ScrollPane root = new ScrollPane(imageView);
root.setPannable(true);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
```

Comment: Is there a way to add Children to the scroll pane. I have a decent size program which added and removes children from the pane. Now when I change it to ScrollPane. It doesn't let me do this. It has this getChildrenUnmodifiable() instead of gentChildren() method

Comment: @Alex: Add a pane containing the image and the additional children to the scrollpane instead of just the image.